# In C# Visual Studio I have randomized my question order but how do I link my questions to the answers

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm really new to coding and have tried to find the answer but I don't understand how to implement it for my code. I need to add an answer for each word in the String I'm not sure if what I have done is right but when i try to run the program the Main in `public static void Main()` comes up with a red underline

```
        public partial class Level1 : Form
{
    public Level1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class InitilizationSample
    {
        public class Questionwithanswer
        {
            public string Question { get; set; }
            public string Answer { get; set; }
            public Questionwithanswer() { }
            public Questionwithanswer(string question)
            {
                Question = question;
            }

        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Questionwithanswer questionwithanswer = new Questionwithanswer { Question = "ZUZB", Answer = "BUZZ" };

            List<Questionwithanswer> Questionwithanswer = new List<Questionwithanswer>
            {
                new Questionwithanswer {Question = "ZUZB", Answer = "BUZZ"},
                new Questionwithanswer {Question = "HXAO", Answer = "HOAX"},
                new Questionwithanswer {Question = "MXAE", Answer = "EXAM"},
                new Questionwithanswer {Question = "KYCU", Answer = "YUCK"}
            };
            System.Console.WriteLine(questionwithanswer.Question);

            foreach (Questionwithanswer c in Questionwithanswer)
                System.Console.WriteLine(c.Question);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `If I needed to add an answer for each word in the string`

Comment: @zaitsman as in each word in the string is like a question and has an answer, so "ZUZB" answer would be "buzz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, at some point you probably want to incorporate your own classes. However, building on the previous code, you could have the List keep track of the randomly selected question/word, and then have a dictionary that contains the word as the key, and the answer as the value in the key/value pair.

In this simple example, there are two buttons and two labels. The nextButton gets the next randomly selected word. Clicking the answer button displays the corresponding answer to that question.

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<string> strStrings = new List<string>() { "ZUZB", "HXAO", "MXAE", "KYCU", "CWEH", "PHIC", "HOCP", "SXIA", "ISHF" };
        Dictionary<string,string> dictStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "ZUZB", "Answer 1" },
            { "HXAO", "Answer 2" },
            { "MXAE", "Answer 3" },
            { "KYCU", "Answer 4" },
            { "CWEH", "Answer 5" },
            { "PHIC", "Answer 6" },
            { "HOCP", "Answer 7" },
            { "SXIA", "Answer 8" },
            { "ISHF", "Answer 9" },
        };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (strStrings.Count > 0)
            {
                string rndWord = strStrings[rnd.Next(0, strStrings.Count())];

                lbljumble.Text = rndWord;
                strStrings.Remove(rndWord);
            }
            else
            {
                lbljumble.Text = "No more questions!";
            }

            answerLabel.Text = "";
        }

        private void answerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string answer = (dictStrings.TryGetValue(lbljumble.Text, out answer)) ? answer : "";
            answerLabel.Text = answer;
        }
```

A slightly more complex solution would be to create class with questions, answers, and a used flag in order to keep track of which ones have had the answer display. Then you can randomize the list once, and then work through them one at a time. Something like:

```
        public Random rnd = new Random();
        public List<QA> listOfQAs;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listOfQAs = new List<QA>() {
                new QA() { Question = "ZUZB", Answer = "Answer 1", Used = false },
                new QA() { Question = "HXAO", Answer = "Answer 2", Used = false },
                new QA() { Question = "MXAE", Answer = "Answer 3", Used = false },
                new QA() { Question = "KYCU", Answer = "Answer 4", Used = false },
                new QA() { Question = "CWEH", Answer = "Answer 5", Used = false },
                new QA() { Question = "PHIC", Answer = "Answer 6", Used = false },
                new QA() { Question = "HOCP", Answer = "Answer 7", Used = false },
                new QA() { Question = "SXIA", Answer = "Answer 8", Used = false },
                new QA() { Question = "ISHF", Answer = "Answer 9", Used = false }
            };

            listOfQAs = listOfQAs.OrderBy(l => this.rnd.Next()).ToList();
        }

        private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<QA> listOfUnused = listOfQAs.Where(l => l.Used == false).ToList();
            if (listOfUnused.Count() > 0)
            {
                QA rndQuestion = listOfUnused.First();
                lbljumble.Text = rndQuestion.Question;
            }
            else
            {
                lbljumble.Text = "No more questions!";
            }

            answerLabel.Text = "";
        }

        private void answerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QA answer = listOfQAs.Find(l => l.Question == lbljumble.Text);

            if (answer != null)
            {
                answerLabel.Text = answer.Answer;
                answer.Used = true;
            }
        }

        public class QA
        {
            public string Question { get; set; }
            public string Answer { get; set; }
            public bool Used { get; set; }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't be afraid to create new types to encapsulate concepts together. You aren't limited to working with built in types.

```cs
public struct Word {
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
List<Word> Quiz = ...;
```

Comment: so where would I put my questions and answers? in the brackets where get set is?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers

Comment: I tried to use this to do it but I have many red lines under my code? do u mind telling me what I need to change? I changed my code to what my answer was ^^

Comment: Jeremy is trying to get the point across, that you should associate a Question with an Answer to make a new thing, perhaps called QuestionWithAnswer (calling it Word is not a great choice in my opinion), and then you randomize the QuestionWithAnswer objects. At the moment you're defining a question list and an answer list and they're only related by the order on which they appear. Then you're reordering the questions which ruins the link to answers. You need to spend a bit more time designing your program on pen and paper- right now you're coding by trial and error